# Function with a generic parameter type

Tags: generics, types, rust, parameters, rust-rocket

I am using the Rocket web framework and I need to create a function with a generic parameter type parameter:

```
use rocket_contrib::json::{Json, JsonValue};

fn bluid_succes_response<T>(data: T) ->  JsonValue  { 
    json!(data) 
}
```

This is the error I have:

```
the trait `dataStructures::parameters_structures::_::_serde::Serialize` is not implemented for `T`
```

How can I implement the `Serialize` trait for a generic type like `T` or is there another way to solve the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to constrain the generic type `T` to a trait (`Serialize` in this case):

```rust
use rocket_contrib::json::{Json, JsonValue};

fn bluid_succes_response<T: serde::Serialize>(data: T) ->  JsonValue  { 
    json!(data) 
}
```